# Can a demigod drown?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew, religions-and-deities

I'm starting a new 5e campaign with my players where they are all demigod, inspired by this blue text https://i.stack.imgur.com/EySDs.jpg

They are still figuring who they want to be and what God they want to be a demigod of. In the story, the demigod are immortal, and don't require food, water, or air. The subject of drowning came up because one player wants to control water, and in case he were to betray the party, they wanted to know if they would be safe or not.

The writer in the story does mention their god stops them from breathing, which he said wouldn't kill him, just would feel bad. I'm just not sure if drowning would be different.

Is there anything RAW or canon that says immortals or gods can't drown, or that beings that don't require air wouldn't drown?

Edit: if not 5e, do the other editions have this information. I thought I had seen books specifically about deities.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver Our policy on this stack is that answers in comments aren't acceptable: https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/. Answers that don't really answer the question don't get posted as answers *or* comments, by design, so it's probably best to just leave that one be. If you feel you can offer RAW/canon at some point please do post an answer if you'd like. We stay very on-purpose with comments since the broader internet presence of our hobby is rife with arguments at the drop of a hat, and we need to do this to avoid having the same here.

Comment: So if you're making up the rules surrounding demigods, which is what it sounds like from your question, isn't it up to you?  Or are you using some rules for demigods in 5e I'm not familiar with?

Comment: There are very vague rules about level 20+ because they haven't come out with anything official to my knowledge, but I haven't read everything released yet.  So I don't know if it is mentioned in modules or anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're overthinking this. 5e has little to no canon guidance on powerful supernatural entities other than gods, celestials, and fiends, beyond what can be surmised from the Warlock class description and the fact that gods come and go from the pantheon over time (and between editions), as described in SCAG.

But more importantly, 5e isn't *the sort of game* that would explicitly spell out something like what you're asking. A lot is left up to GM interpretation. In this case, you have more to work with than usual: you know explicitly that you don't require air. Given that, there's no reason for drowning to be a concern. At most you would be inconvenienced by being waterlogged and slightly heavier on land, or being in the water where it's hard to move.

Comment: Added as an edit: what about in other editions, I had heard they have their own books dedicated to deities and the like.

Comment: If you want to ask about other editions, I'd write a new question for the one(s) you are interested in. As you say, another edition may have a lot of resources on the topic so trying to retroactively include all that in this question would probably degrade its quality.